# Dynamically update specific cell value based on active cell

Tags: excel, vba

Example:
I want to dynamically update cell A1 when I am using the down arrow to move down a range of B1:B10.

For example, if I have 1 - 10 in cells B1:B10 respectively, cell A1 will always update to the contents of whichever cell is active within that specified range.

My current code is this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Not (Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("$B$1:$B$10")) Is Nothing) Then
          Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(Selection.Row, 1)
     End If

End Sub
```

This code does not update the cell with the value of the active cell. However, if I enter a number in A1, then select any cell in the specified range, it deletes the contents of cell A1.

My knowledge of VBA is pretty limited, so if you have an answer to my problem, I would **greatly** appreciate an explanation to how it works.

Comment: Perhaps try `Intersect(Target, Range("$B$1:$B$10")`? (Instead of `ActiveCell`)

Comment: Are you sure about your code?... For what you said, there's a little mistake in the third line. It should be Cells(1, 1) = Cells(Selection.Row, 2). I've just made this change and it works perfectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the number for the column at the third line...
I've just tried your code, and it works perfectly. The only thing wrong is the column at the third line.

Cells(Selection.Row, **COLUMN 2!**)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Not (Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("$B$1:$B$10")) Is Nothing) Then
      Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(Selection.Row, 2) '<--- CHANGE IT HERE
 End If

End Sub
```

Or you could try

```
Range("A1") = Range("B" & Target.Row)
```

instead of

```
Cells(....)
```

for the whole third line.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer

Comment: It would be nice to earn points for an answer given, but I really didn't help so much... you already had done the job. It was just a single number that was wrong. :-)